# Can't select root 'mdRecord' element in XSLT transform

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a set of XML records with 'mdRecord' root elements and dcterms sub-elements that I am trying to transform with XSLT, but I can't figure out how to select the root element.

The original XML records are all like this one (I removed the URLs from the namespaces because otherwise the post gets flagged as spam):

```
<mdRecord 
  xmlns:rdf="[url]" 
  xmlns:dcterms="[url]" 
  xmlns:edm="[url]" 
  xmlns:xsi="[url]" 
  xmlns:dc="[url]" 
  xmlns="[url]" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="[url]">

 <dcterms:spatial>[data]</dcterms:spatial>
 <dcterms:identifier>[data]</dcterms:identifier>
</mdRecord>
```

And I have a simple XSLT transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="[url]" 
  xmlns:xsi="[url]"
  xmlns:oai_dc="[url]"
  xmlns:dc="[url]"
  xmlns:dcterms="[url]"
  xmlns:mods="[url]"
  xmlns:rdf="[url]" 
  xmlns:edm="[url]" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="[url]"
  exclude-result-prefixes="oai_dc dc dcterms xsi rdf edm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <mods:mods>
      <xsl:call-template name="dataProvider"/>
    </mods:mods>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template name="dataProvider">
    <xsl:for-each select="mdRecord">
      <mods:note type="ownership">
        <xsl:text>University of Northern Colorado</xsl:text>    
      </mods:note>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I get as a result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mods:mods xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"/>
```

Why doesn't the 'select="mdRecord"' work?

Comment: Well, if you have `xmlns="[url]"` your `mdRecord` is in that namespace and you need to select elements in that namespace while your current code selects elements named `mdRecord` in no namespace. With XSLT 2.0 you can use `xpath-default-namespace="[url]"` for your whole stylesheet or that template or that for-each to ensure `mdRecord` selects elements with local name `mdRecord` in a particular namespace. So this is basically the most frequently asked question on XSLT and a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, Martin Honnen. Adding `xpath-default-namespace="[url]" to the namespaces worked. I have never properly understood how namespaces work. Sorry for the overly-common problem, and thanks for your assistance.